# (Development) PHP Twitter API Library

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth

I'm working on the development of a *Twitter Oauth API*. The project that is under development is available below.

I have encountered a problem and have trouble resolving it. The issue is; Twitter API functions such as status', friendship requests which I send out using the POST function do work.

Though, when int type data is Included, I get the following

**error code: 32 message: "Could not authenticate you."**

I get this when I include the **statuses/update** function with the ***in_reply_to_status_id*** function or with functions like **favorites/create, favorites/destroy, statuses/retweet, statuses/unretweet** which require int type data (**ID**).

**Index.php Code: (My App Consumer Keys Placed)**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("TwitterClass.php");

    $twitter = new Twitter('srFixTitKV8f9WmJwF6VehhSF', 'GqSR29NQ0RoDBQ8gywQrsLV3vXowgFsSIMmueVQPm7E4ALAkNH');
    $status = $twitter->post('statuses/update', ['status' => 'Test2!', 'in_reply_to_status_id' => '1057346977753636864'], true);
    if ($status) {
        echo 'Success!';
    }
?>
```

The GitHub page for the project under development is available through the link below. Thank you for your help.

[Project Github Page (TwitterClass.php source code)](https://github.com/sercanarga/TwitterOauthApi/blob/master/TwitterClass.php)

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you forgot to add is equal to true, like this: `== true);` instead of `true);`.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is bigger than this.